# Как вывести статью на сайт?

Tags: modx, cms

Добрый вечер!

Есть сайт, сделанный на абсолютно незнакомой `cms - MODx`. Одна из статей добавлена, но не отображается на сайте. Как вывести эту статью на сайт? Галочки типа "публиковать", "дата публикации" и другие очевидные варианты уже перепробованы.

Что еще необходимо сделать, чтобы статья отображалась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от структуры сайта.

1. Создайте шаблон
2. В шаблоне пропишите директиву `[*content*]`
3. Создайте статью, в качестве шаблона укажите только что созданный
4. Установить параметр "публиковать"

К статье можно обратится 2 способами, по id и по alia. Алиас указывается в настройках публикации статьи

```
http://yoursite.kz?id=23
или
http://yoursite.kz/mymat-alias-bla
```

Если вы используете вариант с алиасами то в конфигурировании сайта нужно дать разрешение на эту опцию.
Если на сайте нет динамического меню, то смело создавайте шаблон и размещайте там меню с ссылкой, которую я описал выше

PS рассмотрен вариант для Modx Evo. И не плохо бы увидеть сайт